# How do you send a txt message to a cell phone from a Lucee web app?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I would like my application to send a text message to users on certain triggers, preferably using something like a cfmail tag.  I've never had to send text message from a web app before, but given the huge number of mobile devices out there today I assumed this would be built into CF/Lucee if I ever needed it.  However, now that I do I'm not seeing anything in the docs or first few pages of Google.

Is it possible to send text messages directly from Lucee?  I know that I could use cfmail to send messages to the carrier's gateway (ie: xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net), but that requires me to know and maintain a list of every carrier's address scheme and know which carrier the recipient is with, which I can't.  Is what I want to do only possible with a third party service?

Comment: Not sure how much Lucee supports SMS, but here's the CF help page on SMS https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-external-resources/using-the-sms-event-gateway/about-sms-and-coldfusion.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio (https://www.twilio.com/try-twilio) makes it easy to send text messages. All you need to do is to make an HTTP POST request.

When you successfully send a message, Twilio responds with data about the process, including a message SID (System ID).

Here is some code which you can put in a `.cfm` page and run it to send a message. Replace the three `PLACEHOLDERS` with your Twilio values.

You'll find your Twilio credentials `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN`, on your "Dashboard" after you signup/login at Twilio.

`YOUR_TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER` should start with `+`.

---

```
<cffunction name="sendMessageWithTwilio" output="false" access="public" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="aMessage" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="destinationNumber" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset var twilioAccountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID" />
    <cfset var twilioAuthToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" />
    <cfset var twilioPhoneNumber = "YOUR_TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER" />

    <cfhttp 
        result="result" 
        method="POST" 
        charset="utf-8" 
        url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#twilioAccountSid#/Messages.json"
        username="#twilioAccountSid#"
        password="#twilioAuthToken#" >

        <cfhttpparam name="From" type="formfield" value="#twilioPhoneNumber#" />
        <cfhttpparam name="Body" type="formfield" value="#arguments.aMessage#" />
        <cfhttpparam name="To" type="formfield" value="#arguments.destinationNumber#" />

    </cfhttp>

    <cfif result.Statuscode IS "201 CREATED">
        <cfreturn deserializeJSON(result.Filecontent.toString()).sid />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn result.Statuscode />
    </cfif>

</cffunction>

<cfdump var='#sendMessageWithTwilio(
    "This is a test message.",
    "+17775553333"
)#' />
```

---

Comment: I just wanted to stop back and say that I had a chance to try this and it worked perfectly; just dropped the code into my cfc and I was done.  I wasn't expecting such a complete solution in an answer; you saved me an hour or two of work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any way to do it natively in ColdFusion, but I've used Twilio to send SMS messages from ColdFusion using the Twilio API:  https://www.twilio.com/sms

They offer free developer accounts so you can try before you buy.

Comment: Thank you.  How steep is the learning curve?  Is their API simple enough to setup and write a cfc for in a single night?

Comment: Here is another example it in use: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1966-sending-sms-text-messages-from-twilio-using-coldfusion.htm

Yes it can be done in a day

Answer (score 4):

Virtually all mobile carriers can receive an email and forward it on as a text (SMS) message.

- [Send an email as text to an AT&T wireless number](https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/wireless/KM1061254?gsi=S6z2DWE)
- [Send text messages using email (Verizon)](https://www.verizon.com/about/news/vzw/2013/06/computer-to-phone-text-messaging)
- [How to Send Text Messages Via Email to Sprint Customers](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/send-text-messages-via-email-sprint-customers-53286.html)

We keep a DB table populated with all current carriers and their email-to-text domains. A user can update their profile with their cell number and have to select a mobile carrier before they get an option to receive text messages.

From AT&T's site:

> **Text message** - Compose a new email and enter the recipient's 10-digit wireless number, followed by @txt.att.net. For example, 5551234567@txt.att.net.
>
> **Picture or video message** - Compose a new email and enter the recipient's 10-digit wireless number, followed by @mms.att.net. For example, 5551234567@mms.att.net.

You simply use `<cfmail>` to send text messages as if they were normal emails.

Comment: I had considered this originally, but it presents two problems.  First, we need to maintain that database, and if a carrier ever changes their format our system would stop working.  More importantly, we need to know what carrier the recipient is on, which is nigh impossible for us; we often have only a name and phone number.

Comment: That's completely understandable. We have only had to change that DB a few times in the last couple of years: to add Google and a couple of other new mobile carriers and to deprecate some now defunct carriers. Our UI enforces the user's selection of carrier, but if you can't do the same, then this won't be an option.